# Linux: How to start and run executables from PHP using exec() or shell_exec()

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

I know this can sound strange but I am willing to run an executable file on linux via PHP exec().
What I do now is just write the exact same command I use in the CLI to start and run the executable but it does not seem to work. No errors, no error logging, nothing.

Is there something I am missing?

Here is a code sample:

```
$cmd = './home/user/Desktop/test';
$response = exec($cmd, $out);
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: you are missing **the code**. without showing it to us, **how** do you expect us to be able to find any errors?

Comment: Please post your source code so we can understand what you're trying to do :)

Comment: This is what I am doing: 
I have an executable file named "test" and located at "/home/user/Desktop".
I want to run that executable from PHP using `exec()` or `shell_exec()` like this:

`$cmd = './home/user/Desktop/test';`
`$response = exec($cmd, $out);`
`var_dump($out);`

This produces nothing but the same command launches the executable from the CLI.

Comment: Apologies @FranzGleichmann, I have appended some code to my comment above.

Comment: the leading dot in your path means "start from where i am". so when you execute your script while being in `/var/www`, this will equal to the path `/var/www/home/user/Desktop/test`. which probably won't work. lose the leading dot to use an absolute path. and check for file privileges. oh, and **enable error reporting**

Comment: @FranzGleichmann losing the leading `.` doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

[shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) should work. Make sure you are giving the correct path.

Comment: It doesn't. Am I missing something? All permissions and ownerships are set.

Comment: Is your safe mode turned on?

Comment: I am not working in safe mode. Everything seems normal. @bhazero025